# Html not showing up in outlook mail

Tags: c#, html, outlook

I have the following code that is sending emails to different recipients in a loop

```
public void SendMail2(string subject, string body, string emailAddress, string cc)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = subject;
        mailItem.To = emailAddress;
        mailItem.CC = cc;
        mailItem.Body = body;
        mailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "name";
        mailItem.Display(false);
        mailItem.Send();
    }
```

However the html is just showing up as text with all the tags in the email, while it was perfect when i was using

```
        // Create the Outlook application.
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        // Get the NameSpace and Logon information.
        Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

        // Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
        oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);
```

but I had to revert back to the first method so i can change the "From" address

Any ideas please?

Comment: I don't use C# quite often, but I believe there must be some method to set the Content-Type of the email. Set it to text/html and you are good to go

Comment: As mentioned below, the only change that was needed was mailItem.HTMLBody = body;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `mailItem.HTMLBody = Body;` instead of `mailItem.Body = body;`, and then add `mailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML;`

Comment: With this I get, "The name 'Body' does not exist in the current context" and "The name of "olFormatHTML' does not exist in the current context" also.

Answer (score 4):

> mailItem.Body = body;

That is because you use the [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) property. Use the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) instead.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much, couldnt tick answered for another 8 minutes.

Comment: That's what worked for me, too; all the other ideas wouldn't even compile for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
mailItem.IsBodyHtml= true;
```

will do what you want if I understand your problem

Comment: With this I get, "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem' does not contain a definition for 'IsBodyHtml' and no extension method 'IsBodyHtml' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"